# how to show full size image on clicking thumbnail in gridview

Tags: android

In my project i want that whenever anyone clicks on thumbnail , full size image should open in an activity which user can zoom . but facing problem in passing the url of image (i used arraylist).

below is the code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class NoticeList_Seminar extends AppCompatActivity {

GridView gridView;
ArrayList<Notice_Activity_Seminar> list;
Notice_List_Adapter_Seminar adapter_seminar = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.noticelistlayout_seminar);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter_seminar = new Notice_List_Adapter_Seminar(NoticeList_Seminar.this, R.layout.noticeitemslayout_seminar, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter_seminar);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
            // passing array index
            //intent.putExtra("id",i);
            //startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"full image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Cursor cursor = App_Activity_Seminar.sqLiteHelper_seminar.getData("SELECT * FROM NOTICE_SEMINAR");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String date = cursor.getString(2);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);
        list.add(new Notice_Activity_Seminar(id, name, date, image));
    }
    adapter_seminar.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

**code for FullImage activity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import static com.example.shakshi.demo.R.id.imageView;

public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
   Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id

    int pos = i.getIntExtras("position",0);

    imageView.setImageResource(Notice_List_Adapter_Seminar.noticeList[pos]);


   /* Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
  Notice_List_Adapter_Seminar imageAdapter = new 
 Notice_List_Adapter_Seminar(FullImageActivity.this);

     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
```

imageView.setImageResource(Notice_List_Adapter_Seminar.noticeList[position]);

```
}
```

}

changes i have done

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int 
        i, long l) {



            String url = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
            Intent intent = new Intent(NoticeList_Workshop.this, 
             FullImageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

**in Full Image Activity**

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");


   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
   imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(url));
```

Comment: send full coad ot try this- http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-gridview-zoom-images-animation-tutorial/

Comment: I'm not down voting your question but to be frank you would have got after googling it or just a little bit of research and that is how you learn. Doing this you'll get down votes which will lead you to be blocked from asking question here. All the best

Comment: i am sorry but new to android and i was trying but was not able to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Use `gridViewOnClickListener` and `Intent`.

```
GridView grdview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        grdview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String url = list.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        });
```

In `SecondActivity` `onCreate()` method,

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
```

Set the Source of `Imageview = url;`

Comment: i tried this but when i click on thumbnail the app crashes

Comment: Please share the error message detail you are facing.

Comment: Where exactly is the error? Line? Did you tried debugging you code?

Comment: i have added the changes , please suggest corrections.

Comment: why are you adding an empty list to the adapter?
list = new ArrayList<>();     //This creates an empty array list  

Empty list is being passed 
adapter_seminar = new Notice_List_Adapter_Seminar(NoticeList_Seminar.this, R.layout.noticeitemslayout_seminar, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter_seminar);

Comment: Try adding this at the very last line of onCreate method. gridView.setAdapter(adapter_seminar);

Comment: String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) 
      findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
       imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(url));    i am using this to  set image resource but image preview is not available . only blank screen is visible . how to resolve this

Comment: Why setImageResource? As you mentioned, the image is a Url right? If the image is Url, try using it as Uri as follows

        Uri imageUri = new Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        img.setImageURI(imageUri);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gridview. You get onItemClickListener which also gives you the position of the item which got clicked. So in your onItemClickListener you can get the image url from the arraylist at that position and pass it to your next activity.

And if you are using Recyclerview then you can use callback pattern and using that you can send the same url as a String on which the user has clicked to the containing activity. You can then pass this url to the next activity.